# Using .rik files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS and want to import and view the Swedish .rik.

I am looking for simple instructions how to import the .rik files into QGIS and then view and print the maps.

Answer (score 1):

Those are **raster layers** which you can import from the menubar:

```
Layer > Add Layer > Add Raster Layer and then select the type as Swedish Grid RIK.
```

[image: Adding RIK raster files]

---

Depending on which QGIS version you are using, you can create a composer map (QGIS 2.x) or layout map (QGIS 3.x) which allows you to view and print maps.

Comment: That's great. Thank you for taking the time to answer. After I have imported the maps, is it possible to add text and arrows to the map before printing? And is it possible to use coordinates to locate points on these maps once they are imported into qgis?

Thanks again.

Comment: Most welcome. Yes, you can add texts and arrows before printing. There should be buttons on the sidebar to let you do this and more from the layout/composer. And you can type in coordinates in the QGIS main window at the bottom, it should be on the statusbar aptly named "Coordinates" :)

Comment: Hi Joseph. Thanks again. Really helpful. My original rik files are incompatible with Qgis, but I have found some older ones that work well.

Comment: @dodgyviking - No problem and glad you got it working to some extent!